# changing disk size of a running instance in openstack

Tags: openstack

I have installed OpenStack on a server which has 400 GB - hard disk. There are four instances and each of them was set up with 10 GB.

I need more space for one of the node. Is it possible to increase disk size of a running instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with **nova resize** command.